# Edit client-side jQuery from server-side NodeJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

So here is what I'm trying to do :

index.js ( is a server-side NodeJS file ) has a receiving webhook function. This file will receive an event when some new msg has been received from Facebook.

So what I'm trying to do is to toggle the click event in the client side, where there is a javascript file named : conversation.js and here is the conversation.js file :

```
var conversations = {
    // Resize elements to fit on screen
    // This is really just a temporary hack instead of using endelsss hopurs getting the css/html 100%.
    resize: function () {
        $("#content .user_conversation").css("width", $(window).width() - $("#left_menu").width() - $("#content .conversationcards").width());
        $("#content .user_conversation").css("height", $(window).height() - $("#header").height());
        $("#content .user_conversation").css("left", $("#content .conversationcards").width() + 4);

        $("#content .conversation_typing").css("top", $(window).height() - $("#content .conversation_typing").outerHeight() - $("#header").height());

        if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
            $("#content .conversation_user_info").css("display", "none");
        } else {
            $("#content .conversation_user_info").css("top", $("#content .conversation_name").height() - 1);
            $("#content .conversation_user_info").css("height", $("#content .user_conversation").height() - $("#content .conversation_typing").outerHeight());
            $("#content .conversation_user_info").css("left", $("#content .user_conversation").width() - $("#content .conversation_user_info").width());
            $("#content .conversation_user_info").css("display", "block");
        }

        if ($("#content .conversation_user_info").css("display") == 'none') {
            $("#content .conversation").css("width", $("#content .user_conversation").width());
        } else {
            $("#content .conversation").css("width", $("#content .user_conversation").width() - $("#content .conversation_user_info").width());
        }
        $("#content .conversation").css("height", $("#content .user_conversation").height() - $("#content .conversation_typing").outerHeight() - $("#content .conversation_name").height());

        $("#content .conversation_messages").css("top", $("#content .conversation_name").height() );
        $("#content .conversation_messages").css("width", $("#content .user_conversation").width() - $("#content .conversation_user_info").width() );
    },

    // Start the functionality
    start: function () {
        var html = "";
        // Load ongoing conversations
        $.get("/facebook/conversations",function(data){ 
            var pageConversations = (JSON.parse(data)).data;
            // Get info about users
            for (var i = 0; i <= pageConversations.length - 1; i++) {
                html = html + conversations.createConversationCard(pageConversations[i]);
            }
            $("#content .conversationcards").html(html);
        });
    },

    getUserFromArray: function( id, array ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if ( array[i].facebookid == id ) return array[i];
        }
    },

    // Get user from database
    getDialog: function( id, callback ) {
        // Load dialog from database
        var html = "";
        $.get("/dialogs/id/" + id,function(data){
            console.log('find this ' + data);
            callback( JSON.parse(data) );
        });
    },

    // Get user from database
    getUser: function( id, callback ) {
        // Load dialog from database
        var html = "";
        $.get("/dialogs/user/" + id,function(data){
            callback( JSON.parse(data) );
        });
    },

    // Creates a conversationcard
    createConversationCard: function (conversation) {
        // Get data about the user who started the conversation
        var user= JSON.parse( $.get({url:"/facebook/user/" + getConversationStarter(conversation.senders.data).id,async: false}).responseJSON );
        console.log(conversation);
        console.log( user );
        var output = {};
        output.latesttext = conversation.snippet;
        output.id = conversation.id;
        output.name = user.name;
        output.avatar = user.picture != undefined ? user.picture.data.url : "";
        output.formatted_time = formatTime( conversation.updated_time );
        return Mustache.render($("#templates #conversations .conversationcard").html(), output);
    },

    showConversation: function (conversationid) {
        var conversationmessages = JSON.parse($.get({url:"/facebook/conversation/messages/" + conversationid,async: false}).responseJSON).data;
        var conversationinfo = JSON.parse($.get({url:"/facebook/conversation/" + conversationid,async: false}).responseJSON);
        var user = JSON.parse( $.get({url:"/facebook/user/" + getConversationStarter(conversationinfo.senders.data).id,async: false}).responseJSON );
        console.log( conversationid );
        console.log( conversationmessages );
        console.log( conversationinfo );
        console.log( user );

        var output = {};
        output.name = user.name;
        $('#content #message_input').data("userid",user.name); // To do : changed from id to name.
        $('#content #message_input').data('conversationid', conversationid); // added by MAziar

        output.avatar = user.picture != undefined ? user.picture.data.url : "";
        output.background = user.cover != undefined ? user.cover.source : "";

        var messages = "";
        //for (var i = conversationmessages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var i = 0; i < conversationmessages.length; i++) {
            var m = {};
            m.usermessage = conversationmessages[i].from.id == user.id ? "usermessage" : "";
            m.avatar = user.picture != undefined ? user.picture.data.url : "";
            m.text = conversationmessages[i].message;
            // Check for attachments
            if ( conversationmessages[i].attachments != undefined ) {
                // Check if file attachment
                if ( conversationmessages[i].attachments.data[0].file_url != undefined ) {
                    m.attachment_file = true;
                    m.attachment_url = conversationmessages[i].attachments != undefined ? conversationmessages[i].attachments.data[0].file_url : "";
                    m.attachment_name = conversationmessages[i].attachments != undefined ? conversationmessages[i].attachments.data[0].name : "";
                }
                // If image
                if ( conversationmessages[i].attachments.data[0].image_data != undefined ) {
                    var image = conversationmessages[i].attachments.data[0].image_data;
                    m.attachment_image = true;
                    m.attachment_url = image.animated_gif_preview_url != undefined ? image.animated_gif_preview_url : image.preview_url;
                    //m.attachment_width = conversationmessages[i].attachments.data[0].image_data.width;
                    //m.attachment_height = conversationmessages[i].attachments.data[0].image_data.height4;
                }
            }
            // Check for shares
            if ( conversationmessages[i].shares != undefined ) {
                m.attachment_image = true;
                m.attachment_url = conversationmessages[i].shares.data[0].link;
                m.attachment_width = 40;
            }

            messages = messages + Mustache.render($("#templates #conversations .conversation_message").html(), m);
        }

        // Fill the header for the conversation
        $("#content .conversation_name").html(Mustache.render($("#templates #conversations .conversationname").html(), output));
        $("#content .conversation_user_info").html(Mustache.render($("#templates #conversations .users_info").html(), output));
        $("#content .conversation_messages").html(messages);
        $('#content .conversation_typing').css("display", "inherit");
        $('#content #message_input').focus();



    },

    // Dummy/Test
    getDummyPerson: function (id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dummy_conversations_data.length - 1; i++) {
            if (dummy_conversations_data[i].id == id) return dummy_conversations_data[i];
        }
    },

    // When a message should be posted to the user
    postMessage: function( inputField ) {
        var message = $('#content #message_input').val();
        console.log("Sending data: " + message);
        $.post("/facebook/post/message/" + $('#content #message_input').data("userid"),{text:message},function() {
            console.log ('here the conversationid is ' + $('#content #message_input').data("conversationid") );
            var cid = $('#content #message_input').data("conversationid");
            var msg = message;
            $('#content #message_input').val("");
            conversations.showConversation(cid);
            $(".conversationcard[data-id='" + cid +"']").trigger('click'); // This will do it for send, one for receiving part is needed
            $(".conversationcard[data-id='" + cid +"']").find('.text').html(msg) ;
        //conversations.showConversation($(this).data("id"));
        //conversations.resize();

        });
        return false;
    }

}

// Initilize events for this page
$(document).ready(function () {

    // When a conversationcard is clicked
    $("body").on("click", ".conversationcard", function (event) {
        $(".conversationcard.selected").toggleClass("selected");
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        console.log('look for this : ' + $(this).data("id"));
        conversations.showConversation($(this).data("id"));
        conversations.resize();
    });
});
```

So when an event occures I want to trigger one of the conversationCards with the event click!

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behold, the almighty power of **WebSockets** (smoothly wrapped in an npm library called **socket.io** ([docs](http://socket.io/))

> Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication.
>   It works on every platform, browser or device, focusing equally on reliability and speed.

socket.io can pass server side events into client side actions. Some pseudo example code:

(NodeJS index.js)

```
send: function() {
    io.sockets.emit('reload');
}
```

This is a simple socket 'emit' funciton, which sends a signal to all active webpages. To receive it, we'll check the javascript of the client side:

(script.js)

```
// Define the socket
var socket = io();

// When required to reload, reload
socket.on("reload", function(r) {
    location.reload();
});
```

Now when we're emitting the message 'reload' on the server side, we can 'reload' the page on the client side.

Would this help you on your way?

Comment: I actually tried to use socket.io initially but then I receive an error in server side mentioning that it can't get : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http:// [url]/socket.io/socket.io.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Alright, in that case, +1 for having tried that. Let's see what could be the problem, do you still have code ready with socket.io?

Comment: In the index.hjs I added     <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
to the header. in the conversation.js ( the same file I mentioned in the question "var socket = io();" was the first line. And in the index.js ( the server side code) I had this : var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

Comment: In your `server.js` / `app.js` `main-node-configuration-file.js` file, place:
`io = require('socket.io').listen(server)`

In your route (that serves the page):
`function emit() { io.sockets.emit('reload'); };`

In your client side javascript, place: `var socket = io(); socket.on("reload", function(r) { // your function; });`

Comment: Done that, but still get these two :conversations.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined ( refers to the first line where is "var io = ..." )  and "GET http://sureapp-test.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Are you inserting socket.io.js before your script? Are you inserting it _properly_ as well?

Comment: I'm doing that as well, and that is what causes one of these errors in line 12 saying that socket.io can't be found. ( And can I ask you to move this discussion to chat, since I don't have enough points to do so )

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that as well, or how. Your main issue lies with socket.io.js not being server, have you placed the file in a public folder?

Comment: Now I instead tried this :     <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
But I still get this one :Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined For the like that says : var socket = io();